# How to select a specific <span> with the same class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am attempting to extract some data from this block of HTML.

```
<div class="group-capitalization-content field-group-html-element">
    <h2><span>Capitalization</span></h2>
    <div  class="item">
        <div class="label-inline">Issued &amp; Outstanding:&nbsp;</div>
        <span class="number">242906121</span>
    </div >
    <div class="item">
        <div class="label-inline">Reserved for Issuance:&nbsp;</div>
        <span  class="number">51423534</span >
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using an npm module called `cheerio` to scrape data from HTML. Thus I have the following code to try and get the `"numbers"`.

```
 var data = $('.group-capitalization-content .item .number').text();
```

Running this code results in: `24290612151423534`, which is both results appended together.

How do I select the individual numbers here / separate them?

Comment: You could use a selector for that... [class^="test"]

Answer (score 2):

If the above example is all you need, use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

First items's `text()` is

```
$('.group-capitalization-content .item .number').eq(0).text();
```

...and second is

```
$('.group-capitalization-content .item .number').eq(1).text();
```

If you have a more complex case and you need to store the data in an array, for later, I'd use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) ([`@Sushanth's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43082021/1891677)) - probably a bit more specific, to rule out the possibility of other `.number`s in the page:

```
let data = $.map(
  $('.group-capitalization-content .item .number'), 
  function(e){ return $(e).text() }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could you `map` method and target the `.number` class, which will spit out the contents into an array.

```
let data = $.map($('.number'), function(elem) {
    return $(elem).text();
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know ahead of time how many there will be you can loop through them with an `.each`

```
$('.group-capitalization-content .item .number').each(function() {
    $(this).text(); // Save this to a var or do something with it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `each` function to go through each of your results, like:

```
$('.group-capitalization-content .item .number').each(function(index, element) {
    //your individual item code goes here
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i usually get all the dom elements and then loop over them to do my necessary functions. here is a working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/bbmtk7tm/

```
var data = $('.group-capitalization-content .item .number');
for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
{
console.log(data[i].innerHTML);
}
```